# Find saddle point/local min max of $f(x,y)= (x^2-64)^2-(y^2-16)^2 $

Tags: partial-derivative

**Question**: Find local minima/maxima or saddle points of $$f(x,y)= (x^2-64)^2-(y^2-16)^2 $$
$f_x=4x^3-256=0 \longrightarrow x=0,-8,8;$
$f_y=-4y^3+64=0 \longrightarrow y=0,-4,4$

I am confused about the critical points. Are there 9 critical points? That is, (0,0),(0,-4),(0,4),(-8,0),(-8,-4),(-8,4),(8,0),(8,-4),(8,4)?

$D=f_{xx}*f_{yy}-[f_{xy}]^2<0 $ for all 9 critical values. So these are all saddle points. This just seems unusual that a function has 9 critical points. So, any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: hint: look at the graph and level curves at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+z+%3D+(x%5E2+-+64)%5E2+-+(y%5E2-16)%5E2.

Comment: I would do those derivatives again. I'd probably start by expanding the brackets.

Comment: I actually expanded the function and then did the partial derivatives.

Comment: $$f_x = 4 x (-64 + x^2), f_y = -4 y (-16 + y^2)$$ There are nine critical points. Am I missing something?

Comment: I was surprised to see that there are 9 critical points and I was wondering if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What is $f_x$ and $f_y$? What do they mean? (Not asking for their value.) Sorry if I am a bit amateur at this.

Comment: @user477343 Partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Comment: @TheoBendit so essentially,$$f_x := \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\, f(x)$$ with the same applying for $y$?

Comment: @user477343 Yep, except where $f$ is a function of more than just $x$.

Comment: @TheoBendit ahhh, got it. I just haven't seen the notation $f_x$ before. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @user477343, this is just another way of representing partial derivative of the function with respect to x. I am using Stewart's Calc book and this format is used there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are nine stationary points. You are looking for points at which $f_x$ and $f_y$ take the value $0$ simultaneously. Computing the partial derivatives yields
\begin{align*}
f_x(x, y) &= 4x(x^2 - 64) \\
f_y(x, y) &= 4y(y^2 - 16).
\end{align*}
Solving $f_x(x, y) = 0$ yields $x = 0$ or $x = 8$ or $x = -8$. This doesn't say anything about $y$, so from this equation alone, $y$ can be any number.

On the other hand, solving $f_y(x, y) = 0$ yields $y = 0$ or $y = 4$ or $y = -4$, and $x$ can be any number. The only points at which both equations are simultaneously solved are:

\begin{matrix}
(-8, -4) & (0, -4) & (8, -4) \\
(-8, 0) & (0, 0) & (8, 0) \\
(-8, 4) & (0, 4) & (8, 4)
\end{matrix}

If you're still not sure, try plugging in all nine of these points into $f_x(x, y)$ and $f_y(x, y)$ and verify that both are simultaneously $0$ (the definition of a stationary point).